# Blender Cycles materials not showing in Second Life

Tags: blender, materials

I ran into a problem after trying to import my own creation into second life. While I am not new to 3D modelling with Blender and other programs, I have always only created things for fun. Now I have decided to import few of those creations into Second Life but the materials I have used do not display in the preview at all. I have used the Cycles Render.

How do I solve my issue with Materials not displaying in Second Life after Exporting a Collada file from Blender Rendered in Cycles?

Comment: Generally materials are not portable from one 3D authoring package into another piece of software like a game. Each renderer tends to implement its material system in its own bespoke way, so you may need to author a material in Second Life to approximate the look you had in Blender.

Answer (score 1):

Blenders cycles render engine uses a node based material that does not export to other applications.

To match the cycles material you can [bake](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake) the cycles material to an image and then use the image texture elsewhere.